# app "unfortunately stopped" when touching interstitial ads

Tags: java, android, c++, admob, cocos2d-x

I'm using cocos2d-x 3.2 and I want to show interstitial ad when user touches the screen.
but when I touch the screen I got "Unfortunately Stopped" message.
here is my code:

Java:

```
       @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

final String ADMOB_ID = "ca-app-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000";
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(ADMOB_ID);

AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("3A34952B128D8DC19CCB75CA752ED31B").build();

interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
}

public void showad() { 
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            interstitial.show();
        }
    });
    }
;
```

C++:

```
bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch , cocos2d::Event *event){

    show();
}

void HelloWorld::show(){
       cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;

        if (! cocos2d::JniHelper::getMethodInfo(methodInfo, "org/cocos2dx/cpp/AppActivity", "showad", "()V")) {
            return;
        }

        methodInfo.env->CallVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID);
        methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
}
```

and i've got this error in logcat:

```
A/libc(6628): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00020004 (code=1), thread 6643 (Thread-553)
```

can someone help?(sorry for english :)  )

Answer (score 0):

You have to first load the ad, and then show it:

```
private boolean adIsLoaded = false;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String ADMOB_ID = "ca-app-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000";
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(ADMOB_ID);

    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("3A34952B128D8DC19CCB75CA752ED31B").build();
    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            adIsLoaded=true;
        }
    });

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

}

public void showad() { 
    if (adIsLoaded)
            interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: My app still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a `SIGSEGV` crash, clearly there's nothing to do with your java code, problem appeared on C++ side.

Check `HelloWorld::show()`, print log between each line to find out which line caused the crash. It sounds stupid but effective.

BTW, you have to analyze whole log nears the crash point instead of the line when it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getStaticMethodInfo() and CallStaticVoidMethod() instead. Also make showad() a static function.

It works pretty good for me. But when I use getMethodInfo() and CallVoidMethod() along with non-static java function, neither the code works nor does it crash. It simply does not do anything.

Haven't figured out the reason yet!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it in this way :

```
    private static AppActivity _appActiviy;
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final String ADMOB_ID = "ca-app-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000";
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId(ADMOB_ID);

    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("3A34952B128D8DC19CCB75CA752ED31B").build();

    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public static void showAd(){
    _appActiviy.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {

    @Override
     public void run(){ 
         if (_appActiviy.interstitial.isLoaded())
            {_appActiviy.interstitial.show();}

};
});}
```

c++

```
bool HelloWorld::onTouchBegan(cocos2d::Touch *touch , cocos2d::Event *event){

    show();
}

void HelloWorld::show(){
       cocos2d::JniMethodInfo methodInfo;

        if (! cocos2d::JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(methodInfo, "org/cocos2dx/cpp/AppActivity", "showAd", "()V")) {
            return;
        }

        methodInfo.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(methodInfo.classID, methodInfo.methodID);
        methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
}
```